# What is the difference between Array.GetUpperBound(0) and Array.GetUpperBound(1)

Tags: vb.net

What is the difference between Array.GetUpperBound(0) and Array.GetUpperBound(1) in VB.Net?

Comment: `(0)` or `(1)` is the dimension of the array whose upper bound needs to be determined. [Read the documentations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index applies to the dimension of the array.

For example, if you define the following array:

```
Dim A(2, 4)
```

You can call:

```
A.GetUpperBound(0) 'returns 2
A.GetUpperBound(1) 'returns 4
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te0ke63a(v=vs.110).aspx

Also QUICK TIP: If you are not sure or unfamiliar with a particular function, property object etc. Select the text with the mouse and hit F1..
[image: Select the function name]